# jdbc batch update for oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am using executeBatch() to insert data into oracle. The problem i am facing only occurs for one table. If my batch size is 1000 i get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException but it works well if the batch size is 500. And this happens only for one table which has around 38 columns with raw,nvarchar,varchar and number data, for all other tables it works fine.

So is there any limit on size of the batch? Or is there anything that i am doing wrong?

```
if(counter==500)
{
            try{

                log.info("trying to execute batch with"+counter);
                int done[]=rowInsertStmt.executeBatch();
                rowInsertStmt.clearBatch();
                conn.commit();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                log.info("error while executing batch with counter"+counter);
            }
            counter=0;
            log.info("executed batch "+counter);

}else if(counter<500)
{
            rowInsertStmt.addBatch();
            counter++;
}
```

Comment: In which line of code is `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` reported?

Comment: int done[]=rowInsertStmt.executeBatch();

Comment: your driver version please ? seems there's a bug with Oracle related to this. [Citation here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21432290)

Comment: i am using odbc6 thin driver

Comment: Try again by downloading the latest jar version, or you may have to limit your batch size.!

Comment: I _think_ there will be a limit on the total size, in bytes, of the batch. Meaning there is no definite batch row size that can be depended upon. In this case, `1000` rows worth of data for that table appears to exceed it. If this is the cause, the error message is not particularly helpful.